# Not able to import matplotlib animation with "Permission denied: 'convert'"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, conda

When trying to import `animation` from `matplotlib`, we keep getting the following error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'convert'

This is the complete log:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from matplotlib import animation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 737, in <module>
    class ImageMagickWriter(ImageMagickBase, MovieWriter):
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 120, in wrapper
    if writerClass.isAvailable():
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 730, in isAvailable
    return super().isAvailable()
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 427, in isAvailable
    return shutil.which(cls.bin_path()) is not None
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 724, in bin_path
    binpath = mpl._get_executable_info('magick').executable
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 384, in _get_executable_info
    return impl([path, "--version"], r"^Version: ImageMagick (\S*)")
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 324, in impl
    args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/ssy/miniconda3/envs/bao/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'convert'
```

Any body knows why and how to resolve this?

We are using `conda` for managing the environment. Other packages all work fine. e.g.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import matplotlib
>>> from numpy import arange
```

These all works fine.

Comment: Have you installed imagemagick?

Comment: No, that's what's missing. thanks!

Comment: Hi Jody, I do get the same Error as Yuchen but surprisingly I don't get it when running as sudo? So installing ImageMagick should not be necessary... Do you know why this could be the case?